# Adding Recursively to Set

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm trying to wrap my head around recursive functions with this one function `def friends(self, name, degree):`. The purpose of this one is to return the set of all friends up to a specified degree (for an address book). It's the last part of a larger class called `class SocialAddressBook:`. The 'degree' in this class allows the user to 'query' friends of friends: degree one is a direct friend, degree 2 is a friend-of-a-friend, and so on.  The code I have is

```
def friends(self, name, degree):
    fs = set()
    if degree == 0:
        return set()
    if degree == 1:
```

which is far as my knowledge on this goes....
also some more context:

> Transitive friendship:

```
Fred → Barb → Jane → Emma → Lisa
Fred → Sue
              Jane → Mary
```

and so my tests are : `a.friends('Fred', 1) == {'Barb', 'Sue'}`

`a.friends('Fred', 2) == {'Barb', 'Jane', 'Sue'}`

`a.friends('Fred', 3) == {'Mary', 'Barb', 'Jane', 'Sue', 'Emma'}`

`a.friends('Fred', 4) == {'Barb', 'Emma', 'Mary', 'Lisa', 'Sue', 'Jane'}`

it only goes up to degree 4. <strike>SO should I even do this recursively or just manually since I know the degree it goes up to?</strike>.

If anyone could point me in the right direction on how to complete this recursively, that'd be awesome, thanks!

Comment: Not answering your question directly, but you might prefer to google "breadth first search" for this (using a queue as the storage).  Recursion is better suited to depth first search (uses the call stack as the "storage").

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here, maybe you could elaborate for me. But nevertheless, I think the answer your looking for is, "recursively will be less on the memory(this really doesn't matter here unless you have a few gigabytes of data), while non-recursively will be faster." So I suggest that you have a manual dictionary unless you have a ton of data.

Comment: @PrestonHager hmmm I think I'm mostly just confused on how to use recursion in this case (also just realized I can't hard code the test cases so I'll edit to be more concise). But yeah memory or speed isn't really an issue in this case.

Comment: @plshalp what do you mean by "how" to use recursion in this case?

Comment: @PrestonHager my main problem is syntax. I know what happens when degree == 0 (that's simple enough) but if it's greater than 0, I need to add each person in the set of friends and then add on the return value when I call the function again for each individual friend. And the idea of having to call on the function within that same function, I think is confusing me right now

Comment: Ok. I think this makes sense. And based off of what you gave me in that comment, I agree with the current answers, you should to it iteratively. Thanks for elaborating.

Answer (score 2):

I would say to do this iteratively: just make it add friends to the current list **n** times, where **n** is an input parameter.

```
fs = set(self)
for i in range (n):
    wider = set()
    for chum in fs.copy():
        for new_chum in chum.friend_list:
            fs += new_chum
```

At each level, make a wider set from the friends of the current set.  Once you've been through all of those, add them to the friend set.  Repeat **N** times.

Comment: You should be able to simplify this by removing `wider` and just appending directly to `fs`. Also, `for chum in fs:` :)

Comment: Thanks for the **in** correction.  Appending directly won't work the way we want: it alters **fs** while we're iterating through it.

Comment: ah, fair point... although you could also use `for chum in fs.copy():`

Answer (score 2):

It is best to do this iteratively.

```
def get_friends_iteratively(self, name, degree)
    if degree < 0:
        raise ValueError('degree should be an int >= 0')
    if degree == 0:
        return set() # no friends of degree 0!
    friends = self.friends
    for _ in range(degree):
        new_friends = set()
        # it is important not to change a set while we iterate through it.
        # thus, we change new_friends, then update friends when we are done.
        for other_person in self.friends:
            new_friends |= other_person.friends
        friends |= new_friends
    return friends

    # In python, the |= ('in-place or') operator updates a set with
    # the union of itself and another set.
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: `TypeError` means incorrect type... in this case, `ValueError` would be the appropriate exception... and I think you mean `>= 0` in your exception message.